# Is it possible to store the caption of an image on the right inside list?

Tags: graphics, enumerate, itemize

Is it possible to store the caption of an image on the right inside an itemize list? So I have images and want to enumerate them and add the caption on the right side instead of below the image:

[image]

EDIT: I want to do something like below, no enumerating, just some images on the left side of the item in a \itemize section and a caption on the right. The images should occur inside the list of figures if possible.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{figure}[H]
  \includegraphics{Images/Sample1234.png}
    \caption[abc] {abcdefgh}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\item \begin{figure}[H]
  \includegraphics{Images/Sample.png}
    \caption[blablabla] {adhfiusgvb}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: do you  want to add  captions to list of figure?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to enumerate them like 1. blabla 2.whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}% just for the example

\renewcommand\labelenumi{\textbullet}

\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]{%
%\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\unexpanded{#1}}%  %   if  list of figure needed
My nice image \theenumi{} #1}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \includegraphics[scale=.15]{example-image} \mycaption{caption} 
\item \includegraphics[scale=.15]{example-image} \mycaption{an other caption} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}% just for the example

\usepackage{linegoal}


\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\unexpanded{#1}}
\quad\parbox[b]{\linegoal}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{itemize}
\item \includegraphics[scale=.15]{example-image} \mycaption{caption} 
\item \includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image} \mycaption{an other caption} 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would have gone with \refstepcounter{figure} and \thefigure, but probably this is good enough.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I just  suppose that the  OP want images  to  be numbered this way as he used caption1, caption2

Comment: Sorry, my failure, I didn't want to enumerate the captions in any way. Just have images on the left and the captions on the right inside a list (\enumerate) item.

Comment: I have edited my question to make it more understandable.

Comment: @FranzHuber23 please see update.

Comment: @touhami: Just one more thing: Is it possible to have the images with numbers in the `List of figures`? Right now it looks a bit strange: [See here](http://abload.de/img/strangenumberingnmjdl.jpg)

Comment: Ok, my question with the numbers was answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330196/numbering-in-list-of-figures-with-images-in-an-itemize-list-on-left-side)