# Numbering in list of figures with images in an itemize list on left side

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, itemize

According to my prior [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328957/is-it-possible-to-store-the-caption-of-an-image-on-the-right-inside-list): Is it possible to get the images in the **list of figures** numbered in an itemize list with images on the left side? Right now it looks a bit [strange](http://abload.de/img/strangenumberingnmjdl.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}% just for the example

\usepackage{linegoal}


\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{figure}%
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}{\ignorespaces  #1}}
\quad\parbox[b]{\linegoal}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{itemize}
\item \includegraphics[scale=.15]{example-image} \mycaption{caption} 
\item \includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image} \mycaption{an other caption} 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```