# Different text in list of figures with images in an itemize list on left side

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, itemize

According to my prior questions: [First](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328957/is-it-possible-to-store-the-caption-of-an-image-on-the-right-inside-list) and [Second](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330196/numbering-in-list-of-figures-with-images-in-an-itemize-list-on-left-side). Is it somehow possible to have a different caption than what's shown in the list of figures? So what i want to do is basically the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}% just for the example

\usepackage{linegoal}


\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{figure}%
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}{\ignorespaces  
#1}}
\quad\parbox[b]{\linegoal}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{itemize}
\item \includegraphics[scale=.15]{example-image} \mycaption{caption} \myTitleInListOfFigures{This is another text}
\item \includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image} \mycaption{another caption} \myTitleInListOfFigures{This is another text 2235434t}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Does someone know how to do this?

So the list of figures should then look like:

```
1.1 This is another text
1.2 This is another text 2235434t
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with the help of etoolbox package. To be used

```
\mycaption[This is another text (for list)]{caption (for body)}
```

if another text  is needed or just

```
 \mycaption{caption}
```

if same text need to be used

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}% just for the example

\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\newcommand{\mycaption}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{figure}%
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}{\ignorespaces  
\ifblank{#1}{#2}{#1}}}
\quad\parbox[b]{\linegoal}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{itemize}
\item \includegraphics[scale=.15]{example-image} \mycaption[This is another text]{caption} 
\item \includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image} \mycaption{another caption} 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Strange, I'm getting the optional argument as caption of the image (where should be "caption" is "This is another text")

Comment: it works like this: `\mycaption[text in list]{caption in body}` and if you want same text you can use `\mycaption[caption]{caption}` or simply `\mycaption{caption}`

Comment: No, I found the problem, where there's `linegoal{#1}` it should be `#2`. See for yourself.

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos ok, i see it, i am sorry.

Comment: No need for apologies! We're here for helping right? :D

Comment: @touhami: Thank you for all your suport ;) You literally saved me :D I would give you 500 upvotes if it was possible :P

Comment: @FranzHuber23 you're welcome, glad that i help :-)